# error compiling AEScrypt using mingW-w64 in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw

I downloaded AESCrypt library in order to compile with MingW:
https://github.com/paulej/AESCrypt/tree/master/Windows

I receive this error message:

```
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Temp\cclSPvvW.o:aescrypt.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined re
ference to `sha256_starts(sha256_context*)'
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Temp\cclSPvvW.o:aescrypt.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined re
ference to `sha256_update(sha256_context*, unsigned char*, unsigned long)'
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Temp\cclSPvvW.o:aescrypt.c:(.text+0x815): undefined r
eference to `aes_encrypt(aes_context*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Temp\cclSPvvW.o:aescrypt.c:(.text+0x829): undefined r
eference to `sha256_update(sha256_context*, unsigned char*, unsigned long)'
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/.
./lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libming
w32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined refe
rence to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am on `Windows 7 x64`, I am using `MingW-w64 6.1.0`.

Comment: Show the command used to compile

Comment: Use capital letters for AES

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error means you forgot to link the file containing the code of the missing symbol. It is usually a .o or .lib/.a file.

In your case one of the symbols is: sha256_starts(sha256_context*), which is probably in sha256.o. Check the actual link command and make sure it includes this file or the library which includes it.

A makefile like this should make the trick:

```
COMP = gcc
RM = rm -f
OBJS = aes.o sha256.o stdafx.o AESCrypt.o AESCryptShellExt.o AESCryptWorkerThreads.o BufferedFile.o ErrorHandling.o PasswdDialog.o ProgressDialog.o
LDFLAGS = -mwindows
SERVERLDFLAGS =
TARGET = aes.exe

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(COMP) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $^

clean :
    $(RM) *.o

%.o : %.c %.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

%.o : %.cpp %.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: I am on Windows and no .o or lib/ required, please take a look at github repository, thank you.

Comment: The link error means it cannot find the binary code for sha256_starts and sha256_update. If you look at sha256.c, you will find the implementation of these functions. This means you have to compile sha256.c to generate sha256.o, then when you link your files together, this file must be included with the other .o to get the executable file.

Comment: How then to compile it using mingw ? what is the solution ?

Comment: gcc -c file.c or gcc -c file.cpp to generate file.o, then gcc -o target.exe *.o to link the program (makefile in the edited initial post). How do you currently compile?